# Is that possible to let "multilog" program output human-readable file name instead of TAI64N timestamp name?

Tags: logging, logrotate, log-rotation

I am using "multilog" to do log rotation in debian server.

When the log roates, "multilog" will create a filename as `@TAI64N_timestamp.s` or `@TAI64N_timestamp.u`.

I know I can convert TAI64N timestamp to human-readable format by using `tai64nlocal` tool. But it's really not that convenient.

Can I let "multilog" to output human-readable time format file name directly somehow?

Thanks a lot.